# Como rodar wmv na tag <video> (Google Chrome)?

Tags: html5, vídeo, html-tags

Não estou conseguindo rodar arquivos .wmv, .mpg por exemplo, no chrome via tag .

O código é mais ou menos este,

```
<video id="video1" class="videos">
    <source src="temp/meuVideo.wmv" type="video/wmv" />
</video>
```

Conforme imagem abaixo, o vídeo não carrega neste formato.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me informar se há algum modo de faze-los rodar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WMV** não é suportado nativamente pelo Chrome ou Firefox

Não há meios de fazer funcionar sem que cada usuário instale em seu próprio computador "adicionais" para conseguir rodar o vídeo, o que é totalmente inviável.

Recomendo que converta o vídeo em wmv para formatos abertos, como `WebM` e como *fallback* para navegadores mais antigos e o navegador Safari crie um MP4 (MPEG-4/H.264, não é um formato aberto).

Formatos suportados pelo Firefox:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox#w_supported-formats

Como detectar suporte com JavaScript:

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/video#check-formats

Para converter pode usar https://ffmpeg.org/